# Finding conditional pdf using Bayes law

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = C(x+y3) $$ for $0\leq x\leq1$, $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise for some constant $C$. Find $P(X<0.5 \mid y\leq 0.5)$.

My attempt:
First, find the marginal distribution of $y$
$$f_Y(y) =  \frac{C}{2} + Cy^3 $$
Then, use Bayes law
$$f(x \mid y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} = \frac{2(x+y^3)}{1+2y^3} $$
Then, integrate this function within the limits $(0,0.5)$ for both $x$ and $y$ to arrive at the answer. Is this approach correct? If yes, computing this integral is a bit nasty. Is there an easier way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What conditional expectation? $P(X<0.5\mid Y\le 0.5)=\frac1{P(Y\le 0.5)}P(X<0.5,Y\le 0.5)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom sorry, I meant conditional pdf. Edited the title.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should find the constant $C$ from the property

$$\int^1_0 \int^1_0 f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx\,dy = 1.$$

Then, you can use the simpler definition of conditional probability of events:

$$P\left(X<0.5\,|\,Y<0.5\right) = \frac{P\left(X<0.5,Y<0.5\right)}{P\left(Y<0.5\right)}$$

where

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(X<0.5,Y<0.5\right) &=& \int^{0.5}_0 \int^{0.5}_0 f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx\,dy,\\
P\left(Y<0.5\right) &=& \int^{0.5}_0 \int^{1}_0 f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx\,dy.
\end{eqnarray*}